# Ubuntu 16.04 + HP LJ MFP132nw (USB) Failed to scan

Tags: 16.04, hp, scanner

I want to configure the HP LaserJet Pro M132nw MFP to scan in Ubuntu 16.04

Installed hplip 3.16.11
Installed printer through:

```
Hp-setup -i
```

The printer work fine, but when I'm trying to scan there is the message that it can not find the scanner.

sane-find-scanner

```
User @ test: ~ $ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # Sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # Result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # Scanner is powered up and connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expect something different, make sure that
  SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

Found USB scanner (vendor = 0x03f0 [HP], product = 0x622a [HP LaserJet MFP M129-M134]) at libusb: 001: 010
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # Can not be detected by this program.
```

`scanimage -L`

```
User @ test: ~ $ sudo scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
Check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
Sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
Which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Printer settings (CUPS)

```
Description: HP_LaserJet_MFP_M129-M134
Location:
Driver: HP LaserJet MFP m129-m134, hpcups 3.16.11 (color)
Connection: hp: / usb / HP_LaserJet_MFP_M129-M134? Serial = VNC8Y01706
Defaults: job-sheets = none, none media = iso_a4_210x297mm sides = one-sided
```

GUI Simple scan - sees the scanner in the settings, but when you try to scan it produces:

```
"Failed To Scan, Unable to connect to scanner"
```

Reinstalled the hp-plugin

Added a line to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`

```
 # Hewlett-Packard LaserJet M132NW ATTRS {idVendor} == "03f0", ATTRS {idProduct} == "622a", ENV {libsane_matched} = "yes"
```

Added a line in `/etc/sane.d/hp.conf`

```
# HP M132NW
Usb 0x03f0 0x622a
```

User in groups:

```
User @ test: ~ $ groups
User adm lp cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare scanner
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
For me the solution was this: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE/Scanner-specific_problems#HP
In other words, in the Terminal:
"hp-setup -i"
"hp-plugin -i"
"hp-scan"
(I installed XSane and tried it before that. It didn't seem to help, so probably is irrelevant...)
After that Simple Scan worked.